# Dart library mutual import with polymer

Tags: import, dart, polymer

I have a polymer element containing another one. I tried to have them in the same library like the following

### In parent.dart

library Parent;

part "child.dart";

### In child.dart

part of Parent

But this doesn't work. I guess because the child.dart is also included in child.html (the polymer template file.) So I separated them into two libraries and have they like

### In parent.dart

library Parent;

import "child.dart";

### In child.dart

library Child;

import "parent.dart";

This works but I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Yi

Answer (score 0):

It's an emerging best practice to give each custom element its own library.